# Parsing Nginx logs

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to use Python to parse the Nginx error log file to determine if something happened in the last 15 minutes then do some things based off that.

I have nothing significant to show yet because I am totally unsure about how to do this. I have the rest of my script done in the sense it does everything I need except parsing the log file. I have looked google and on SO but have not found anything that would help me. I figured out how to check the last say 10 lines but that doesn't solve the time issue.

I'm hoping someone can give me some direction. Or an example of how to parse a log file including the time and error message *show below as `error I need to find`

I know there is no code and SO normally wants code though I have nothing to show for this part of the script and don't think there is a better stack exchange place to ask this question. Seems a bit basic for the software engineering one.

This is an example of the log file entry that I need to find a

```
2019/03/15 14:22:59 [error] 14064#0: <error I need to find>, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: example.com, request: "POST /hello", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: Have you tried regex?

Comment: @DelenaMalan No I have not, I tend to really suck at it. I am sure I could get it though I would have to create the date/time format and be able to compare. Does Python's version of `new Date()` go to the same format as the nginx logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression pattern to find the different parts of the logs that you are interested in. You can isolate the different parts using round brackets, `(` and `)`, into "groups". For example, if you are interested in the date and the error message of a line in the log file you could use Python's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module like this:

```
import re
pattern = `^(\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(.+), client`
match = re.search(pattern, line) # where line is a single line in the log
date_time = match.group(0)
error_message = match.group(1)
```

You can see what each part of the pattern I used is for and play around with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/lWO4QS/1).

Since you're only interested in the logs of the last 15 minutes, you could either use another regular expression or Python's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module to parse the date and compare it to the current time. You could also do a combination of the two and write a less complex pattern that would eliminate obviously old logs before converting the date to a `datetime` object.

To create a `datetime` object from the date string that you got above, you can use the [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method. It parses a string into a `datetime` object given a format. You can specify the format using the directives listed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). You could write a method like this to check if the date string is within the past 15 minutes:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

MAX_DIFF = timedelta(minutes=15)
DATE_FORMAT = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"  

def is_recent_date(date_string):
    current_time = datetime.now() 
    date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, DATE_FORMAT)
    diff = current_time - date_object
    return diff < MAX_DIFF
```

Comment: Wow thank you! This seems like exactly what I need. I had started to do the regex (as suggested by someone else) but yours is way better.

Comment: @JoshKirby glad I could help :)